# Can you move from one repository to another with Tortoise?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Ok, I am using Tortoise Subversion in Vista and using VisualSVN on a Windows Server 2007 dev server.

Originally I was just using my own instance of Tortoise not on a server but just my local PC until they got me my dev server.  So I had a bunch of commits and comments going on.  So the url to the repository was this:

```
https://mylocalpc:8443/svn/MyLocalRepositoryName/trunk/WebProjectName
```

The structure was that I had a single repository called WebProjectName and then under it branches, tags, and trunk folder:

```
MyLocalRepositoryName
    branches
    tags
    trunk
```

Now that I have an actual dev server, I created a new repository and set it up a bit different.  I created one main repository and then folders for each of our projects...WebProjectName being one folder.  And under each project folder the 3 folders (branches, tags, trunk).  So it looks like this

```
DevRepositoryName
    WebProjectName
         branches
         tags
         trunk
    SomeProject2
         branches
         tags
         trunk
    ....
```

And the url to the WebProjectName on my dev server would be:

```
https://devserver/svn/DevRepositoryName/WebProjectName/trunk
```

My quesiton now is, I want to use the new repository and folder called WebProjectName in place of my local...since now we're using a dev server thank God.

But I don't want to loose all the commit history and comments that I had locally under my local server.

Can you somehow port all that stuff over to a new repository AND to a structure that is completely different than what I was setting up locally?

If so, how would you go about this specifically using the Tortoise context menu in Windows and commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that the best solution would be to change the structure of your existing repository then move that over to the dev server.

First, set up the structure (using the SVN Move... items in the right drag context menu) to be what you want.

Once that is done, copy the repository over from your local machine to the dev server.

Finally, perform a Relocate on your working copies to point to the appropriate path on the dev server.

Comment: But I don't want the repository to have the same name..it's a different name on our dev server.

Comment: When you move, I assume you don't include the .svn folder in a move.